# How to extract list of values in an XML node using Java

Tags: java, xml, w3c

Below is the relevant XML code:

```
<extendedDataElements
    name="Access"
    type="noValue">
    <children
        name="item-key"
        type="string">
        <values>00005</values>
    </children>

    <children
        name="access-type"
        type="string">
        <values>Search</values>
    </children>

    <children
        name="key-type"
        type="string">
        <values>Store</values>
    </children>

</extendedDataElements>

<extendedDataElements
    name="Version"
    type="string">
    <values>Core: 3.2.0, Enum: 3.2.3, Log4j1: 3.2.0</values>
</extendedDataElements>
```

I have the two `extendedElements` objects successfully loaded into a `NodeList`. What I want to do, is isolate the second `<extendedDataElements>` object (which I have done below), and extract all of the Strings in the `<values>` tag, into a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();

NodeList extendedDataElementsNodeList = commonBaseEvent.getElementsByTagName("extendedDataElements");

//successfully isolates the <extendedDateElements> tag with a list of strings in the <values>
Node secondExtendedDataElementNode = extendedDataElementsNodeList.item(1);
```

How can I extract the comma-separated list of values in the `<values>` tag, into a List ?

Put simply, how can I extract all of the info within the  tag of the following XML:

```
<extendedDataElements
    name="Version"
    type="string">
    <values>Core: 3.2.0, Enum: 3.2.3, Log4j1: 3.2.0</values>
</extendedDataElements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for get attribute's values

```
String name = secondExtendedDataElementNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
String type = secondExtendedDataElementNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue();
```

firstly get the comma-separated values into the Array

```
String[] commaSeparatedValue = secondExtendedDataElementNode.selectSingleNode("values").getText().split(",");
```

then add these values into the List,

with java8

```
valuesList = Arrays.stream(commaSeparatedValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with  java9

```
valuesList = List.of(commaSeparatedValue);
```